# Sprites disappearing after camera catches up with player Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I am having an issue where all the sprites in-game disappear after the camera following the player catches up with it but all sprites are still visible on the scene view? The code for my camera is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CamMovement : MonoBehaviour {

   public Transform target;
   public float speed;
   public bool M;

   void Start () {
   }

   void Update () {
       if (M == true) {
           transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
       }
   }

   void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D C){
      if (C.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
         M = false;
      }
   }
   void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D C){
       if (C.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
           M = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks, I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: This doesn't seem like enough information for us to work with. Can you start with providing us screenshots of the properties of your camera and one of the affected sprites?

Comment: Maybe clipping on the camera, but like Serlite said we need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are setting the target equal to your player object. [The camera clips near and far by default](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html), so objects at the same z level will not show on the camera.

Change your code like this so that it will stay far enough away on the z axis, and it should work:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, transform.position.z), speed * Time.deltaTime);
```